# Best Practice for Helper/Partial that render a Model driven select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's assume I have a model Product, and I want a drop-down select box that contains all products.  This drop-down is used in several views, so it is going to be created by a helper method.  Where is the 'best practice' location to get the select options from Product?  Do I set `@products = Product.all` in every controller action that needs to show the drop-down, or do I make the helper method self contained by having it call `Product.all`?  Does the answer change if I am dealing with a partial, or if I am filtering the products (i.e. `Product.in_category(@category)`)?  MVC says use the controller, but DRY says use the helper.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the collection_select form helper that's built in. You can pass in different collections (Product.all, Product.) as and where needed in different views.

[collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)

From the link:

> collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method,
>   text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
>
> Returns  and  tags for the collection of existing
>   return values of method for object‘s class. The value returned from
>   calling method on the instance object will be selected. If calling
>   method returns nil, no selection is made without including :prompt or
>   :include_blank in the options hash.
>
> The :value_method and :text_method parameters are methods to be called
>   on each member of collection. The return values are used as the value
>   attribute and contents of each  tag, respectively. They can
>   also be any object that responds to call, such as a proc, that will be
>   called for each member of the collection to retrieve the value/text.
>
> Example object structure for use with this method:
>
> class Post < ActiveRecord::Base   belongs_to :author end
>
> class Author < ActiveRecord::Base   has_many :posts   def
>   name_with_initial
>       "#{first_name.first}. #{last_name}"   end end
>
> Sample usage (selecting the associated Author for an instance of Post,
>   @post):
>
> collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id,
>   :name_with_initial, prompt: true)
>
> If @post.author_id is already 1, this would return:
>
> Please
>   select   D. Heinemeier
>   Hansson   D. Thomas   M. Clark

Comment: Going by what you pulled from the docs, the call goes directly in the view, but I am not sure that is enough to clearly answer the question.  I feel that the docs sometimes (often?) neglect best practice for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Well, it's a view helper to create a select list and if what you need in any given view is just that, use it directly. If you want to choose what products, pass in different scopes from the model. If you have more specific needs for the select, you can wrap it in another helper, but it's not clear to me why it should be in the controller. Also, to me a 'best practice' is don't roll your own if it exists. But maybe I'm missing something. Always ready to be enlightened, though. I always am happier to learn of a abetter way.

Comment: Also, look at the link I posted. There are several other interesting alternatives on the theme that again might save you writing your own code.

Comment: -This method is a great for building the select, but my question is where to put the call that gets the select options. In `collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)` the call to `Author.all` has the view talking directly to the model.  Following MVC, `@authors = Author.all` should be in the controller, and the view should use @authors.  But if the select goes on multiple views, across multiple controllers, it is DRYer to put the call to the model directly in a helper that uses `collection_select` (or its kin).  Which way is best?

Comment: As I said in my comment above, there's nothing wrong with creating helper methods like all_products_select that uses collections_select with Product.all and, say, purchased_products_select that uses Products.purchased, etc.

Comment: I guess the DRYest, pure-MVC-est answer is Vimsha's. Create the object in the controller. Maybe create helper methods for the collection_select calls to keep your views streamlined. Assuming you know what you want when the controller is called. Sometimes you don't. I have views that the user can manipulate to change what's displayed. I use render calls that talk to the model scopes directly. Maybe there's a better way. As I said, always learning with this stuff. I also think there's a point of diminishing returns where you can go crazy trying to be too pure too soon. You can always refactor.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Controller should decide what data the user sees. How the user sees it can be decided by the view or by the helper.

So i would advise you to put

```
@products = Product.all
```

or

```
Product.in_category(@category)
```

in your controller

Any kind of filter you apply should be done in the controller as well

Answer (score 0):

With rails being a model-view-controller (MVC) framework, you're going to want that logic to be on the model. Having some method that returns the options for your select would probably be best (though, take that with a grain of salt because these things change a lot with application). Something I might try would be along the lines of:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_select_options(category=nil)
    if category.nil?
      Product.all
    else
      Product.in_category(category)
    end
  end
end
```

... which you could then call with `Product.get_select_options` or `Product.get_select_options(@category)`

Comment: I agree that this method should exist in the model, and I have several that looks like this.  The question is, where does the call to this method go?  The knee jerk answer is that it should go in the controller, but if you have the same select box in several views this is not very DRY, and if you have several such select boxes in the same view you quickly get a fat controller.

Comment: In that case, I would probably use a view helper method, which calls Product.get_select_options.